# Let $a \in X \cap X'$. Then, $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $a$ if, and only if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $X'$ the set of accumulation points of $X$.

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $a \in X \cap X'$. Then, $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $a$ if, and only if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=f(a)$.

Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$ Since $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $a$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that  the condition $|x-a|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. In particular, if $x\neq a$ we have, $0<|x-a|<\delta$, which implies that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. Therefore,  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=f(a)$

Unfortunately, I couldn't prove the result in the opposite direction.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We notice that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$a-\delta < x <a +\delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) -f(a)|<\varepsilon \quad \forall x\in X\backslash\{a\}.$$

Since $x=a \in X$, we have $f(a)$ exists, $|x-a|= 0 <\delta$ and $|f(x) - f(a)| =0< \varepsilon$, therefore we conclude
$$|x-a|<\delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - f(a)|<\varepsilon.$$